# Blackberry Bold ToolTip Issue

Tags: asp.net, blackberry

I have created a asp.net website and i added tooltip to a button by setting Title or ToolTip Attribute. But that tooltip is not getting displayed on blackberry bold. But its displaying in blackberry curve so what should i changed in my code to show tooltip on blackberry bold.

Regards
Ricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of the blackberry browser has been known to not handle certain interpretations of HTML generated by ASP.Net too well.

I've had some strange situation before when testing on BB's. The first place to look is at the version of the browser on the bold and the curve. If the version giving issues is relatively out of date enough for the user base to be insignificant you may be able to forget about it.

If that is not an option, start by including a Blackberry.Config file. An example of how to do this and exactly what it does can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14917/Configuring-Net-2-0-to-recognise-the-BlackBerry-br).

Comment: I just want to update everybody that still i didn't got any help on this.... :( from blackberry forums too

Comment: There is no solution, ASP.Net + old BB browser = :(